# Using %ifmacro with NASM assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Suppose I have this macro:

```
%macro MYMACRO 2-*
    ;some code here
%endmacro
```

These tests pass:

```
%ifmacro MYMACRO
%ifmacro MYMACRO 2
%ifmacro MYMACRO 1-*
%ifmacro MYMACRO 2-*
%ifmacro MYMACRO 3-*
```

And this test doesn't pass:

```
%ifmacro MYMACRO 1
```

My question is: *1* is in *1-** so why *%ifmacro MYMACRO 1-** passes and *%ifmacro MYMACRO* 1 doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [nasm manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.4.2):

> The %ifmacro is considered true if defining a macro with the given
>   name and number of arguments would cause a definitions conflict.

Obviously `1` does not conflict with `2-*`, but `1-*` does.